# What are all of the possible values of the textStatus parameter in the callback function of jQuery .load?

Tags: jquery

I am utilising the callback function of jQuery's [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to run certain code if the `textStatus` parameter of the `.load` method is equal to a certain string.

**e.g. I have**

```
jQuery("#myContainer").load('/seperate-file-with-content.asp', function(responseText, textStatus, xhr){                     
    if (textStatus === "error" || responseText.length <= 0) {
        //file failed to load i.e. textStatus == error 
        //or file loaded but has no content
    } else {
        //file loaded successfully i.e. textStatus == success
    }       
});
```

But i'm worried that the `else` part of the `if` statement may catch other non expected `textStatus` values that aren't equal to `success`.

**Are there any other possible values to textStatus, other than `error` and `success` ?**

**EDIT/UPDATE:** As I now believe that `.load` is based on `.ajax`, the answers in the following question may be of use for anyone else with a similar question:- [In jQuery's ajax success callback, will textStatus ever not be "success"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461491/in-jquerys-ajax-success-callback-will-textstatus-ever-not-be-success?rq=1)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`load()` is based on [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), and the documentation for this method lists the possible statuses as:

- `abort`
- `error`
- `notmodified`
- `parsererror`
- `success`
- `timeout`

Comment: apart from error and success, do you know how I could replicate the above statuses on my page?

Comment: `abort` won't be easy, since `load()` does not return a jqXHR (although `$.ajax()` does), so you cannot abort it to obtain that status. `timeout` is easy to get (have the server hang on the request), as are `notmodified` (have the server reply `304 Not Modified`) and `parsererror` (have the server send invalid markup or JSON).

Comment: thanks for the help, you've answered my original question and more.

Comment: I also got a "nocontent" as the textStatus from a $.getJson request.

Comment: See "complete" and "error" sections in the jquery ajax documentation https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/