# What are passed to success function of $.ajax()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461491/in-jquerys-ajax-success-callback-will-textstatus-ever-not-be-success) and I've gotten insight on what `textstatus` of `success: function(textstatus)` gives. Apparently, there's a set amount of response that is generated automatically based on what happened when I called `$.ajax()`, with one being `success`, right?

However, I've still got questions on the `success: function(data)` part. I specified `dataType: 'json'` in my `$.ajax()` and as expected, I had to `echo json_encode` in my PHP file to get the results I wanted. **However,** I was curious so I tried to do the following:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo ('a');
    echo json_encode(array('a' => 'b'));
    echo json_encode(array('c' => 'd'));
?>
```

Then, I tried alerting inside my `success` function. It didn't work, so I guessed that an error occurred. Then, I tried placing an `error: function() { alert('hi'); }` and it did alert 'hi', indicating that it indeed detected an error. Then, I also tried to `echo('a')` with `echo json_encode(array('a' => 'b'));`. I expected it to return the JSON-encoded result as I did specify that I was expecting `dataType: 'json'`, but oddly, it returned an error.

My questions and assumptions are:

1. How does `$.ajax()`, in simple terms, know which result to take, if at all? What if I had two items that are of the same `dataType` in the same PHP file? An error occurred; I initially thought it would just take the first item and ignore the second `json_encode`ed result. Then I tried `echo`-ing two items w/ different `dataType`s. Again, I assumed that it would simply take the one that suits the `dataType` I specified and ignore the other. However, an error occurred too.
2. In relation to the first question, although probably unnecessary as I can simply pass all the results I want first in an array, how do I pass two **different** (say two arrays) results from one single `$.ajax()` call? Or is that plain impossible or terribly inelegant?

Comment: You are getting an error because you are declaring your output to be JSON in the header but not returning valid JSON. See the possible duplicate for a possible solution.

Comment: @Nick I know, but I did do: `echo 'a'; echo json_encode(array('a'=>'b'));`... The second one is a JSON, right? I do know that I can just pass all the results I want in an array first before `echo json_encode`, but my example above did contain a `JSON` object and a string `'a'`. So I was expecting that it would simply ignore the string part and take the JSON.

Comment: Note, `"\"a\""` is valid `JSON` `console.log(JSON.parse("\"a\""))`

Comment: The problem is that your output as a **whole** must be valid JSON, and if you echo an `a` in front of it, it isn't. If you just `echo json_encode(array('a'=>'b'));` it will be valid JSON and your success routine will run

Comment: You can only return one JSON object `{....}` not `a{...}{...}`  Therefore the only output you can have is a single `echo json_encode(...);` call.

Comment: @WealthyPlayer The thing is that as you said your response will contains a string 'a' and a correct formatted JSON BUT jQuery will evaluate : 'a' + your JSON. So, it is a malformatted JSON and then throw an error as stated in the documentation.

```The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown.```

Comment: @guest271314 yes `"a"` is on it's own, but `"a" { "a" : "b" }` is not

Comment: @Nick Yes, the comment is just a note that a properly escaped string, without `{}` or `[]` included in the string is valid `JSON`. An "ordinary" `HTTP` request does not expect more than one response. `HTTP` is not a streaming protocol, either from client to server or server to client, though `EventSource` and `WebSocket` can be used to stream data to the client, `HTTP/2` is perhaps more suited to "streaming" data, depending on the application.

Comment: @Myerffoeg I see! That makes sense. Could you put that as an answer, please?

Comment: @Nick I see, thank you!